# Open a popover with by ID - Mapbox

Tags: maps, leaflet, mapbox

In mapbox I am creating my overlays using the following code within my map creation function - http://jsfiddle.net/shanejones/3ajankv9/

I now need to work out a way to open a popover by it's ID in a separate function.

Using the post here I have modified it to the following example which should open layer with id 1.

```
function next(next_id){

    map.featureLayer.eachLayer(function(marker) {

        if (marker.feature.properties.id == marker_id) {
            marker.openPopup();
        }

    });

}
```

But all it does is give me an undefined error anyone know where I'm going wrong here?

Edit - To show the error I get when I run the above function from the console.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: "But all it does is give me an undefined error" - please always include the error verbatim in any question. Knowing _what the error is exactly_ is miles more helpful than just mentioning there was one.

Comment: Added a screenshot of the error I'm getting.

Comment: Can you please confirm if the `fiddle` is working?

Comment: Fiddle isn't working as it requires external PHP scripts

The fiddle just shows the JS code.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem in the past. What I ended up doing was something like this, it's not the best solution but it may help you out.

```
 map.featureLayer.eachLayer(function(marker) {
    if (marker.feature.properties.id == marker_id) {
          marker.fireEvent('click', {
                latlng: {
                    lat: marker._latlng.lat,
                    lng: marker._latlng.lng
                }
          });
    }
});
```